# Ubuntu 16.04 Genymotion Android device launches but not work - black screen

Tags: virtualbox, android, genymotion

Before I use Ubuntu 15.04 everything was ok. After I upgrade to 16.04 , I try to launch Nexus 4 - 4.3 as often with Genymotion 2.5.2 but got device with just black screen, I install Genymotion 2.7.2 and got the same problem, after I deleted both 2.5.2 and 2.7.2 I reinstall 2.7.2 again but still same situation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: People help me please! Or at least tell me where can I get support about my question. I already send this issue with logs archive to Genymotion support but still have no news from them.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the same problem with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322338/ubuntu-16-04-genymotion-dev-hw-random-not-found

> Just go to your install directory and delete the libdrm.so.2, then restart.

Use command:

```
cd /genymotion/install/directory
mv libdrm.so.2 libdrm.so.2_bk
```